# Explicit code generation from WSDL file for autocomplete?

Tags: python, soap, autocomplete, wsdl, suds

I'm using [the suds library](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) as a SOAP client in some project.
I would like to know if there was a way to generate Python code according to the WSDL file.

For example, consider the following line to be from the WSDL file:

```
<operation name="GetLastTradePrice">
```

Then, I want to get in some `.py` file the auto-generated function

```
def GetLastTradePrice...
```

The purpose of that is to be able to know what are my possible functions and properties when I have a client.  That means that if I will write:

```
from suds.client import Client
client = Client(SOME_URL)
```

Then, after typing the folloewing

```
client.service.
```

I will get the option of auto-completion `GetLastTradePrice`.

Comment: Just out of interest, is the Python REPL autocompletion framework flexible enough to dynamically change the autocomplete options depending on the state of an object? In an interactive programming environment (like the REPL) this would allow typing "client.service." to dynamically bring up a list of Web Service methods that have been parsed when the client is initialised in an earlier step.

Answer (score 0):

Ye olde [ZSI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ZSI/2.0-rc3) library can generate Python code from a WSDL definition but, compared to suds, it's quite painful to use and requires another really old module called PyXML. I'd stick to suds, auto-completion isn't worth all that.

Answer (score 0):

There are many SOAP server implementations for python, some more usable than others, search for packages related to SOAP at [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=soap&submit=search) or take a look at the wiki page about [web services](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebServices) at python.org. There are essentially two types of SOAP servers for python:

1. Servers that can generate server stubs from WSDL files (like ZSI)
2. Servers that can produce WSDL from the service class methods directly (like soaplib, ladon)